# Palindrome ignoring spaces and punctuation

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sentence = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program will determine if an inputted phrase is a palindrome.");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase, word, or sentence:");
    String a = sentence.nextLine();
    String b = a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]"," "); //as long as the words are spelt the same way, the caps don't matter and it ignores spaces and punctuation
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker(b)); //calls method

}

public static String palindromeChecker(String b) 
{
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(b).reverse().toString();
    String c; 
    if(b.equals(reverse)) { 
        c = "The word " +b+ "  is a palindrome"; }
    else {
        c = "The word " +b+ "  is not a palindrome"; }
    return c;

}
```

}

My, problem is that for example, if i do Eva, can I see bees in a cave? It should be a palindrome, however it's not can u please help me with this and please try not to make it complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
String b = a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]"," ");
```

With

```
String b = a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]","");
```

Otherwise, you're replacing non-alphabetical characters with spaces, which can influence the checking of the reverse String.

Comment: yeah i have to wait for 4 mins

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all non-letters from your string:

```
public class Palindrome {
  public static String strip(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
  }

  public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {
      if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - i)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(strip("Eva, can I see bees in a cave?"));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(strip("Eva, can I see bees in a cave?")));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
evacaniseebeesinacave
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PalindromeStringWithReverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "21raceca r12";
        str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
        boolean isPalindrome = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt((str.length() - 1) - i)) {
                isPalindrome = true;
                continue;
            }
            isPalindrome = false;
        }
        if (isPalindrome) {
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not palindrome");
        }

    }
}
```